# Running VSCode interactive window on WSL with relative imports

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to visualize plots using pyplot `imshow`. Windows' WSL does not work with GUIs so the advised way of doing so is via VSCode's interactive window. However, given my project structure,

```
$projectFolder
├── mycode
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── model.py
│   ├── dataset.py
│   ├── train.py
│   └── predict.py
└── vision
    └── references
        └── detection
            ├── utils.py
            ├── transforms.py
            ├── engine.py
            └── etc
```

the only way I can run my code is using the terminal (`python3 -m mycode.predict`), but then again nothing is plotted because of WSL. Here are my imports:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import torch
from dataset import MyDataset
from model import get_instance_segmentation_model
from PIL import Image
from torchvision.transforms import functional as F
from torchvision.utils import draw_bounding_boxes, draw_segmentation_masks
from train import get_transform

from vision.references.detection import transforms as T
```

I followed [this](https://k0nze.dev/posts/python-relative-imports-vscode/) exactly but still get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vision'` when trying to run via the VSCode 'play' button and/or as interactive window, even though autocomplete works and nothing is highlighted ("No problems have been detected in the workspace"). What am I doing wrong here? Here's my launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "mycode",
            "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/vision/"}
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you using **.env** file. Here is a table which explains the difference between `.env` and `launch.json`:

| Run option | .env setting | launch.json setting |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Run Python file in terminal | no | no |
| Run in interactive Window | yes | no |
| Debug via F5 | yes | yes |
| "Debug Python File" (*) | yes | no |

If you use interactive Window, the settings in `launch.json` will not work.

You can create `.env` file under your workspace then add `"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",` to your settings.json.

**.env**

```
PYTHONPATH=PATH/TO/YOUR/FOLDER
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this. However, I'm unable to run the code via VSCode even without interactive window, so there's still something missing/wrong with the launch.json approach...

Comment: @MartimPassos You can read the [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_prerequisites) and follow the document step by step to find the problem

Comment: Sorry, this isn't helpful. For now I have moved the files I needed in `detection` to `mycode`, but still get ModuleNotFound if they are in anywhere else (or ImportError: attempted relative(...) if I try the dot notation). The .env approach didn't work either, be it for interactive window, the standard "Run Python file" button, or running from the command line without `-m`...

Comment: Have you tried add `"program": "${file}",` to your `launch.json`? And does `.env` file work?